# Как переместить background в другой блок при клике?

Tags: javascript

Есть `input`, который загружает изображения в блок как `background`

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.attached_photo_mess_block').show();
      $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result+')');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Есть идея — чтобы при нажатии на кнопку этот `background` переносился в другой блок:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('#sendimage').on('click', function () 
      {
        $('.message-screen').append('<div class="user_two_message col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><div class="sender-text-image"><div id="imagePreview"></div></div></div>');
        $('.attached_photo_mess_block').hide();
    });
});
```

Как это реализовать, если картинка загружается не с сервера, а с компьютера/телефона пользователя?

Comment: Ну url-то у тебя есть - вот и используй.

Comment: Вам её надо сначало на сервер подгрузить, а потом вставить в `background`